# How to change datepicker button color?

Tags: flutter, dart

Please suggest how to change the button color of datepicker in flutter?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the color by changing the primarySwatch in your theme:

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.pink),
  ...
)
```

Comment: primaryColor is working fine with datepicker header and accentColor is working for selected day value. But I need to change the button text color as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> If you still face null safety problem in changing color in 2021 ..then
> here is the simeple solution

```
       Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget ?child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
          splashColor: Colors.black,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            button: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          accentColor: Colors.black,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Color(0xffffbc00),
              primaryVariant: Colors.black,
              secondaryVariant: Colors.black,
              onSecondary: Colors.black,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              surface: Colors.black,
              onSurface: Colors.black,
              secondary: Colors.black),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: child ??Text(""),
      );
    }
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(1960, 8),
    lastDate: DateTime.now());
if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
  setState(() {
    selectedDate = picked;


    String da = picked.day.toString() +
        "-" +
        picked.month.toString() +
        "-" +
        picked.year.toString();
    dateOfBirth.text = da;
  });
```